# Oracle Dependency for Change Notification in .NET Project

Tags: notifications, odp.net

I'm not having any luck getting the change notification back from the DB server.  My local firewall is off.  We're wondering if there are any other environmental/machine settings that would be preventing the change notification from returning?

My user has CHANGE NOTIFICATION rights on the database.  Server is 11.2.0.2.0 and ODP.NET files are 2.112.1.2.

```
var con = new OracleConnection(constr);
                OracleDependency dep = null;
                var cmd = new OracleCommand("select col1, col2, col3 from gline.test", con);
                con.Open();
                //OracleDependency.Port = 1005;

                dep = new OracleDependency();
                dep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnMyNotificaton);

                dep.QueryBasedNotification = false;
                dep.AddCommandDependency(cmd);
                cmd.Notification.IsNotifiedOnce = false;
                cmd.AddRowid = true;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                var txn = con.BeginTransaction();
                string updateCmdText = "update gline.test set col1 = 1, col2 = 2, col3 = 3 where col1 = 1";
                OracleCommand updateCmd = new OracleCommand(updateCmdText, con);
                updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                txn.Commit();
                Console.WriteLine("updated gline.test");
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for change notification...");
```